# solace - logging in weblogic server console

Tags: solace

I have placed the solace jar files in the below location :

```
  C:\oracle10.3.6\Middleware\user_projects\domains\solace_domain\lib (solace jar files)

  If I have the log4j.properties in application level, how this will effect the logging ?

  As I start the weblogic server it starts printing the INFO login in the server console ?

  Here is my log4j.properites file :
```

Comment: log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=(pattern)
log4j.category.com.solacesystems.jms=ERROR
log4j.category.com.solacesystems.jcsmp=ERROR

Comment: INFO: Entering start()
May 5, 2016 2:18:40 AM com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection start
INFO: Leaving start() : Connection already started
May 5, 2016 2:18:40 AM com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection start
INFO: Entering start()
May 5, 2016 2:18:40 AM com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection start
INFO: Leaving start() : Connection already started
May 5, 2016 2:18:40 AM com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection start
INFO: Entering start()
May 5, 2016 2:18:40 AM com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection start
INFO: Leaving start() : Connection already started
May 5, 2016 2:18:40 AM com.solacesystems.jms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log4j.properties file should be contained somewhere in the Weblogic server's CLASSPATH. You can enable the Java system property "-Dlog4j.debug" to see debug level log4j logs. This will tell you where the properties file is being read from.

If the following is contained in the correct log4j.properties file, you should only be seeing ERROR and FATAL level Solace JMS and Solace JCSMP logs. You should not be seeing INFO level Solace JMS or Solace JCSMP logs on startup.

```
log4j.category.com.solacesystems.jms=ERROR
log4j.category.com.solacesystems.jcsmp=ERROR
```